# Typeerror: Boolean is not a function for login function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, promise

I wrote a function coming from Auth for the user to login. When the user uses the correct credentials login works fine. Also when he types in a wrong email address or password the correct error message is displayed.

However, if he types wrong credentials and thereafter the correct credentials I obtain the

Typeerror: Boolean is not a function for login function

I can't figure why this might happen.

```
$scope.login = function(form) {

        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.login=true;

        if(form) {
          var test=Auth.login({
            username: $scope.user.email,
            password: $scope.user.password
          });

          Auth.login({
            username: $scope.user.email,
            password: $scope.user.password
          })
            .then( function(err) {
              authService.loginConfirmed();
            })
            .catch( function(err) {
              $scope.errors.other =$translate.instant('PASSWORD_MATCH2');
            });
        }
      };
```

It seems that the login is data is not updated correctly. Do I overwrite something?

```
<form class="form auth-tripdelta" name="form" ng-submit="login(form)" novalidate>



    <div class="form-group form-label">
      <label >Email</label>

      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control loggingFields" ng-model="user.email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-label">
      <label>{{'PASSWORD'|translate}}</label>

      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control loggingFields" ng-model="user.password" required>
    </div>


    <div>
      <button class="loginButton loggingButton" type="submit">
        Login
      </button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

Finally the standard auth service looks like this

```
login: function(user, callback) {
          var cb = callback || angular.noop;
          return User.login(user,function() {
            this.updateUser();
            return cb();
          }.bind(this),function(err) {
            //this.logout();
            return cb(err);
          }.bind(this)).$promise;
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a login function in the scope. But in loginfunction you define login as boolean in scope `$scope.login=true;`

then $scope.login is no more a function and would be override from boolean field.

use different names.